# How to keep html div at a fixed position using css?

Tags: html, css

How to keep a `<div>` fixed?

I tried using `style="position:fixed"` but the part I want to keep fixed keeps getting overlapped with the part below it. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mchjqhLc):

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It's already fixed. You must to set a background to it (default is transparent).

Example: `style="position: fixed; background: white;"`

Comment: Well, the "Select product category" header is supposed to be below the blue horizontal bar.. instead, they overlap for some reason

Comment: Maybe you meant `position: static` instead of `fixed` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the position to be fixed? Just have the position be static (default value) or relative.
`<div class="row">`
or
`<div class="row" style="position:relative;">`
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1up1thyw/)

Answer (score 0):

Element is positioned relative to the browser if you use position property value as fixed. It's independents from other elements on the page. if you want to `select` element to be below the blue bar, you have to do something different like this.
value for `margin-top` can be dynamically set through javascript as you want.

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden">
<div class="row" style="position: fixed">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6" align="right">
          <table class="table" id="cart">
            <tr>
              <td>Brand</td>
              <td>Description</td>
                <td>Unit Price</td>
              <td>Qty</td>
                <td hidden>ID</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <div align="left">
            <p id= 'cart_total'>Cart Total:</p>
            <button class="btn btn-success"><a href="/checkout">Checkout</a></button>
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>  
        </div>
        <hr style="border: 5px solid #337ab7">
</div>
    
    <div class="container text-center" style="margin-top: 154px;">
        <h1>Select product category:</h1>
        <select id="product_types">
            <option selected=""></option>
                 <option value="">1</option>
                 <option value="">2</option>
                 <option value="">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```